# Sending MPI_Comm handler via MPI_Send

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I have a quick question: is it possible to send type MPI_Comm (handler of communicator) via MPI_Send/MPI_ISend? Will receiving process be able to use this communicator handler normally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, communicator handles are locally valued objects which means that their value makes no sense in other processes. This is also true for most (if not all) MPI handles. For example, in Open MPI communicator handles are either pointers to structures (C bindings) or indices in an array of pointers to such structures (Fortran bindings), so both make no sense outside of the process where they were assigned.

Comment: You confirmed my thoughts. Thank you.